# The `uniform-distribution` tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are currently three questions under [uniform-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform-distribution). I am not entirely sure if the three questions are using the tag for the same thing. Can someone take a look at it?

Comment: One is closed for a while and was cross-posted on the proper site. I voted to delete, so there will only be two questions to deal with. While looking at them I realized that I can only look, and nothing else.

Comment: Of the other two, the more recent one is really about continuous distributions in general. The older one (the "beach problem") isn't about probability at all, and asks about distributing points on an interval in a specific way. I don't see much in common between them.

Comment: "uniform distribution" has two meanings, one as a specific probability distribution, one as a way of distributing sequences of points in an interval (or in a square, or on a sphere, etc.), where it's more a question of number theory than probability. Maybe distribution-of-sequences is a better tag for the beach problem.

Answer (score 3):

I propose that

1. The beach question be retagged along the lines Gerry Myerson suggests.
2. The tag [uniform-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform-distribution) be merged into [probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions).  The tag wiki for the latter says that it is about

   > Questions on using, finding, or otherwise relating to probability distributions, pdfs, cdfs, or the like.
   >
   > Any probability distribution, including beta, binomial, chi, Erlang, gamma, geometric, logitnormal, negative binomial, normal (Gaussian), Pareto, Poisson, Student's t, uniform, Wald, Weibull, zeta, and Zipf.

   So it specifically includes the uniform distribution.
3. (While we're at it) the tag [geometric-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-distribution) be merged into [probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions) as well, for the same reason as in (2).